# validate dynamic for using react hook form

Tags: react-hook-form

SO i have a form that generates dynamically based on data. I was trying to figure out how to use react-hooks-form to validate the fields.

```
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {fieldSet.map((item,index) => {
                if(item.domain === null){
                  if(item.alias == 'OBJECTID'){
                    return
                  };
                    return (
                        <Grid xs={12} md={12} lg={12} key={index}>
                            <FormControl variant="standard">
                            <InputLabel shrink multiline htmlFor={item.alias}>{item.alias}</InputLabel>
                            <StyledInput disabled={item.editable ? false : true} id={item.alias} onChange={e => setFieldsData(fieldsData => ({...fieldsData, [e.target.id]: e.target.value}))} sx={{"& .MuiInputBase-input.Mui-disabled": {backgroundColor:'grey'}}}>
                              {featureSet.map((data,index) => {

                                if(data.attributes.name == item.name){
                                  return (
                                    console.log('data to browse for validation:', data),
                                    data.attributes.name
                                  )
                                }
                              })}
                            </StyledInput>
                            </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                    )
                } else if(item.domain != null){
                    return (
                        <Grid xs={12} md={12} lg={12} key={index}>
                            <FormControl fullWidth size='small' style={{marginTop:'20px'}}>
                            <InputLabel id={item.alias}>{item.alias}</InputLabel>
                            <Select id={item.alias} labelId={item.alias} onChange={e => setFieldsData(fieldsData => ({...fieldsData, [item.alias]: e.target.value}))} style={{backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                              {item.domain.codedValues.map((values, index) => {
                                return (
                                  <MenuItem key={index} value={values.name}>{values.name}</MenuItem>
                                )
                              })}
                            </Select>
                            </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                    )
                }
            })}
            <Grid container xs={12}>
              <Grid xs={12} sx={{height:'50px', border:'1px solid white'}}></Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={12}>
              <Typography align='center' sx={{display: showUpdate ? '':'none'}}>Data Updated</Typography>
            </Grid>

            {showUpdate ? <Button onClick={handleCloseDialog} fullWidth variant='outlined' style={{marginTop:'10px', borderColor:'white', color:'white'}}>Close</Button> : <Button onClick={submit} fullWidth variant='outlined' style={{marginTop:'10px', borderColor:'white', color:'white'}}>Submit</Button>}
            
          </form>
```

The above code generates an input or a select based on data criteria. None of which is important. What i need to know is to hook up each of these dynamically generated fields to a 'register', i grok the static version well enough, but the useFieldsArray eludes me.

Any takers?